# Paging in iCarousel

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, icarousel

I need to have the paging implemented in *iCarousel*. I have integrated iCarousel with **iCarouselTypeLinear** after that I have written following code:

```
UIView *bandImageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350, 300, 100, 20)];
bandImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:bandImageView];
```

This code has created a red area below the Carousel where I would like to show the paging control.

What are my next steps to implement paging in *iCarousel*.

Zeeshan Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one and see if it helps you
http://snipplr.com/view/60971/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Fuji i understand but i didn't find it logical to paste whole class here because pasting piece of code wont be able to help in this scenario. somebody need to understand the whole flow of page control in reference of carousel.

Comment: The code you pasted has absolutely nothing to do with iCarousel.

Answer (score 7):

Try this ...
Worked for me.

```
    carousel.decelerationRate = 0.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

first set your caroselView type as Linear.

```
[carouselView setType:iCarouselTypeLinear];
```

Second in iCarosel.m file you can see the code to the top. set MAX_VISIBLE_ITEMS 1, it will show 1 view then you can scroll it. I looks like paging.

```
#ifdef ICAROUSEL_MACOS
#define MAX_VISIBLE_ITEMS 1
#else
#define MAX_VISIBLE_ITEMS 1
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

for swift:
carouselView.isPagingEnabled = true

Answer (score 0):

setup your page control, then set up your carousal. once that is done iCarousel can implement a function called CarouselDidScroll. implement this function then inside assign the pageControl.currentPage = carouselView.currentItemIndex

```
func carouselDidScroll(_ carousel: iCarousel) {
    pageControl.currentPage = carouselView.currentItemIndex
}
```